# Mongodb fetch records using multiple date ranges and group by these dates

Tags: mongodb

I have data similar to this in my database

```
 {
            _id: ObjectId(<some mongo default encoded id>),
        user: 45,
event_group: 1,
            events: [
            {event: "event name", current_points:1, date: ISO(2017-05-11 21:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name1", current_points:2, date: ISO(2017-05-11 22:15:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name2", current_points:5, date: ISO(2017-05-11 22:10:55.774Z)},
            {event: "event name3", current_points:8, date: ISO(2017-05-12 23:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name4", current_points:10, date: ISO(2017-05-12 21:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name5", current_points:25, date: ISO(2017-05-14 22:15:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name6", current_points:20, date: ISO(2017-05-14 22:10:55.774Z)},
            ]
          }

{
            _id: ObjectId(<some mongo default encoded id>),
        user: 45,
event_group: 2,
            events: [
            {event: "event name", current_points:10, date: ISO(2017-05-11 21:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name1", current_points:15, date: ISO(2017-05-11 22:15:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name2", current_points:12, date: ISO(2017-05-11 22:10:55.774Z)},
            {event: "event name3", current_points:18, date: ISO(2017-05-12 23:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name4", current_points:25, date: ISO(2017-05-12 21:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name5", current_points:50, date: ISO(2017-05-14 22:15:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name6", current_points:100, date: ISO(2017-05-14 22:10:55.774Z)},
            ]
          }

{
            _id: ObjectId(<some mongo default encoded id>),
        user: 44,
event_group: 1,
            events: [
            {event: "event name", current_points:20, date: ISO(2017-05-11 21:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name1", current_points:15, date: ISO(2017-05-11 22:15:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name2", current_points:30, date: ISO(2017-05-11 22:10:55.774Z)},
            {event: "event name3", current_points:35, date: ISO(2017-05-12 23:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name4", current_points:45, date: ISO(2017-05-12 21:00:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name5", current_points:100, date: ISO(2017-05-14 22:15:45.774Z)},
            {event: "event name6", current_points:120, date: ISO(2017-05-14 22:10:55.774Z)},
            ]
          }
```

I want to fetch records within 7, 15, 30 or more days interval. I need to fetch user's record for all the dates (for each day). Currently I am fetching them using the following query:

```
db.Collection.aggregate(
{"$match":{"user":181}},{"$unwind":"$events"},{"$match":{"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1523471400,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523557799,"usec":0}}}},{"$sort":{"events.date":1}},{"$group":{"_id":null,,"points":{"$last":"$events.current_points"}}});
```

It fetch record for 1 date range, I run this query 7, 15, 30 or more times. Query and data is working well, but its adding more processing on my server. I want to club this query into 1 single query, something like this. Following is the query for fetching records for 7 days.

Thanks for resolving the error in my query Vince Bowdren. Here's my updated query.

How can I group this result via the dates I am fetching this data from. For example, if date is between 2017-05-23 00:00:00 & 2017-05-23 23:59:59 then, the result should also be grouped via this date.

I need to fetch all this data for plotting them in graphs via dates.

```
db.getCollection('Collection').aggregate(
{"$match":{"user":121}},
{"$unwind":"$events"},
{"$match":{"$or":[
    {"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1522780200,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1522866599,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1522866600,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1522952999,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1522953000,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523039399,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1523039400,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523125799,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1523125800,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523212199,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1523212200,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523298599,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1523298600,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523384999,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1523385000,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523471399,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1523471400,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523557799,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1523557800,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523644199,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1523644200,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523730599,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1523730600,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523816999,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1523817000,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523903399,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1523903400,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523989799,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date":{"$gte":{"sec":1523989800,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1524076199,"usec":0}}}
    ]}},
{"$sort":{"events.date":1}},
{"$group":{"_id":"$user","events":{"$push":"$events"},
    "points":{"$last":"$events.current_points"},   
    }
}
)
```

Currently I am getting this result:

```
{
    "result": [{
        "_id": 121,
        "points": 42930,
        "events": [{
            "current_points": 41875,
            "won": 1,
            "date": {
                "sec": 1522780225,
                "usec": 237000
            },
            "event_name": "abc"
        }, {
            "current_points": 41875,
            "won": 1,
            "date": {
                "sec": 1522780225,
                "usec": 237000
            },
            "event_name": "absc"
        }, {
            "current_points": 41875,
            "won": 0,
            "date": {
                "sec": 1522780225,
                "usec": 237000
            },
            "event_name": "abcd"
        }]
    }]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using the [$or conditional](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/or/) incorrectly.

Instead of this:

```
{"$match":{"events.date":
  {"$or":[
    {"$gte":{"sec":1523471400,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523557799,"usec":0}},
    {"$gte":{"sec":1523557800,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523644199,"usec":0}},
    {"$gte":{"sec":1523644200,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523730599,"usec":0}},
    {"$gte":{"sec":1523730600,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523816999,"usec":0}},
    {"$gte":{"sec":1523817000,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523903399,"usec":0}},
    {"$gte":{"sec":1523903400,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523989799,"usec":0}},
    {"$gte":{"sec":1523989800,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1524076199,"usec":0}}
    ]
  }
}},
```

The $or needs a set of independent queries, *each including the field which they're querying*. Try changing it to this:

```
{"$match":{
  "$or":[
    {"events.date" : {"$gte":{"sec":1523471400,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523557799,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date" : {"$gte":{"sec":1523557800,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523644199,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date" : {"$gte":{"sec":1523644200,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523730599,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date" : {"$gte":{"sec":1523730600,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523816999,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date" : {"$gte":{"sec":1523817000,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523903399,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date" : {"$gte":{"sec":1523903400,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1523989799,"usec":0}}},
    {"events.date" : {"$gte":{"sec":1523989800,"usec":0},"$lte":{"sec":1524076199,"usec":0}}
    ]
  }
},
```

Comment: Thanks Vince for correcting my mistake. It's working perfectly now. There's one more problem. However, its not related to this query. When I run this query on my PHP it works fine and fetch the data correctly. But, when it run in robomongo software, it do not show me results (Show this instead: Fetched 0 record(s) in 0ms). Do you have any idea about it?

Comment: That's quite a different problem; I suggest you double-check the connection settings for your PHP and for Robo3T - perhaps they are pointing at different databases or different collections?

Comment: Can we group this data via the dates we are fetching them with? I want to plot them into graphs via the dates we are fetching. Currently its fetching all the sub-documents together.

Comment: Again, a separate question. But yes, it should be possible using the [$addFields](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/addFields/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) operators.

Answer (score 0):

Thats not how you should write criteria inside `$match` block. Edit your query such that it will look like this:

```
{"$or":[
    {"sec":{"$gte":1523471400}},{"usec":{"$gte":0}},{"sec":{"$lte":1523557799}},{"usec":{"$lte":0}}
    ....... //other criteria to be added.
    ]
}
```

Also don't repeat criteria check for `usec`. Just add remaining `sec` match criteria conditions.

Comment: Update your query on the post please.

Comment: Hi @RahulRaj, Can you please check the updated query below my original question?